# bad frame_type in StackMapTable for no reason

Tags: playframework, bytecode, playframework-1.x, javassist

I'm using `Play! framework` 1.3.0, using `javassist` 3.19, and I got

```
BadBytecode("bad frame_type in StackMapTable");
```

from javassist, causing

```
    UnexpectedException:
While applying class play.classloading.enhancers.LocalvariablesNamesEnhancer on controllers.Application
```

Also tested it on several Java8 builds, and with Play 1.3.4.

Any ideas how can I go from here ?

**EDIT**:

I've noticed that it happened when I added many (~50) nested static classes in the same package.

Comment: Did you try filling a bug with the Play! framework?

Comment: I did, just couple of hours ago. It seems related to number of static nested classes per package